# Check Neighbours in a String with Java

Tags: java, loops, character, charat

in a **string** like **"phone"** i want to know the **neighbour** of the **character** **'o'** in this **case** **'h'** and **'n'** i tryed with a String Iterator but that gives me either before or after and with charAt() i will be out of range by -1 or endless loop

```
String s = textArea.getText();
    
    for( int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        char tz = s.charAt(i--);
                            
            System.out.print(ch);
            if(ch == 'n') {
            System.out.print(tz);
            break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like this. Of course, you can still do changes to the code to get the expected result.

```
public void stringSplit(String text)
    {
        char[] letters = text.toCharArray();
        for (int i=0; i<letters.length;i++)
        {
            if (i!=0 && i!=letters.length-1){
                System.out.print("neighbour left: " + letters[i - 1] +'\n');
                System.out.print("actual: " + letters[i]+'\n');
                if (letters[i - 1] == 'n') { //here I used the condition from your code
                    System.out.print("neighbour right: " + letters[i + 1] +'\n');
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if(i==0)
            {
                System.out.print("actual: " + letters[i]+'\n');
                System.out.print("neighbour right: " + letters[i + 1] +'\n');
            }
            else{
                System.out.print("neighbour left: " + letters[i - 1] +'\n');
                System.out.print("actual: " + letters[i]+'\n');

                System.out.println("end of string");
            }
        }
    }
```

In this version you have all the corner cases checked. Do you still have questions?

Comment: Thanks that works! i actually got a nothe question. How would you try to get the User Input by using a JTextAera?  the user is typing some text and i try directly to run it i my code and use a nother JTextArea to print it out? Would be the DocumentListner the best choice?@studs-need-help

Comment: Well you can try to get the input from the user (from keyboard) using a Scanner and then I would convert it to a JTextArea. I think this would be something like this: Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in); JTextArea area=new JTextArea( myObj.nextLine());

Answer (score 1):

`s.charAt(i--)` subtracts one in loop. It it leads to endless loop. You can try `s.charAt(i-1)` instead

Comment: out of range by -1. i guess becouse of the loop. But anyway thanks @Dmitriy Mishenyov

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "phone";
    char[] arr = neighbour(s, 'o');
    System.out.println("previous : "+arr[0]);
    System.out.println("next : "+arr[1]);
}

public static char[] neighbour(String s , char c){
    int index = s.indexOf(c);
    if(index == -1) throw new Error("character '"+c+"' not exist in \""+s+"\" ");
    char[] arr = new char[2];
    if(index > 0)
        arr[0] = s.charAt(index-1);
    if(index+1 < s.length())
        arr[1] = s.charAt(index+1);
    return arr;
}
```

this will get the next and  previous character off specific char and put them inside array of 2 character.