# DocumentListener getting User input in an Array without duplicating them

Tags: java, swing

Like the question title says. Whenever I run the program it will get every key stroke I do but with every next key stroke it will output the key strokes before as well.
For example:

- 1 Key is 'j' output will be 'j'
- 2 Key is 'k' output will be 'jjk'
- 3 Key is 'l' output will be 'jjkjkl'

and so on.

A Running Code you can see below (with some keys that are manipulated not all but all the cases i have in my String manipulator method) and also a picture that shows how the result with the problem looks like which is yellow marked.

```
public class theProgram  implements Runnable {
static JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
 static JTextArea textArea_1 = new JTextArea();
 JButton loeschen;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new theProgram());
    

}

public static void stringManipulator(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String k = string.toString();
    char[] checkV = k.toCharArray();
    
    for( int i = 0; i < k.length(); i++) {
        
        char ch = checkV[i];
        
        
        
        if(ch == ' ') {
            textArea_1.append(" ");
            
        }
        if(ch == ',') {
            textArea_1.append(",");
            
        }
        if(ch == '.') {
            textArea_1.append(".");
            
        }
        if((ch == 'a') || (ch== 'A')) {
            textArea_1.append("a");
            
        }
        if((ch == 'b') || (ch== 'B')) {
            textArea_1.append("b");
            
        }
        if((ch == 'c') || (ch== 'C')) {
            textArea_1.append("c");
            
        }
        
        if((ch == 'd') || (ch== 'D')) {
            textArea_1.append("d");
            
        }
        
        if((ch == 'f') || (ch== 'F')) {
            textArea_1.append("f");
            
        }
        if((ch == 'g') || (ch== 'G')) {
            textArea_1.append("g");
                                        
        }
        
        if((ch == 'v') || (ch == 'V')) {
            if(i!=0 && i!=checkV.length-1) {
            if((checkV[i-1] == 'o') ||(checkV[i-1] == 'u')||(checkV[i-1] == 'û')||(checkV[i-1] == 'w')||(checkV[i-1] == 'z')||
                    (checkV[i+1] == 'o')||(checkV[i+1] == 'u')||(checkV[i+1] == 'û')||(checkV[i+1] == 'w')||(checkV[i+1] == 'z')) {
            textArea_1.append("V");
            
            }
                        
        }
}


@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(900,400);
    frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getSize());
    frame.getContentPane().add(newWindow(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


private JPanel newWindow() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JPanel panel_H = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));
    panel_H.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    
    textArea = new JTextArea(10, 40);
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    
    
    textArea_1 = new JTextArea(10, 40);
    textArea_1.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea_1.setLineWrap(true);
    Document document = textArea.getDocument();
    document.addDocumentListener(new MyListener());
    panel.add(textArea, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    panel.add(textArea_1, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    
    
    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    loeschen = new JButton("Delete");
    loeschen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            textArea.setText("");
            textArea_1.setText("");
        }
        
    });
    loeschen.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (85,25));
    panel_1.add(loeschen, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   
    // Panel 3 für Label oben
    JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(1,3));
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Input");
    panel_2.add(label, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    
    JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Output");
    panel_2.add(label_1, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    
    
    //Alle Panel in Panel_H Schreiben
    panel_H.add(panel_2, BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
    panel_H.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel_H.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   
    return panel_H;
}

private class MyListener implements DocumentListener{

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        textArea_1.setText("");
        textArea.addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());
        stringManipulator(textArea.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        textArea_1.setText("");
        stringManipulator(textArea.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
    
}
```

}

And the Picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shm1G.jpg]

I added a runnable Code delted all the small code snippet which i did before and added the solution in my running code

Comment: Consider posting a [mcve].

Comment: @Abra thanks for the suggestion i will do that later

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do?  If a user types a space or comma, the JTextArea will show a space or comma, respectively.  If a user types the Enter key, the next characters go to the next line of the JTextArea.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc try that one i added and you get my problem

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc i know and thats why i ask for a suggestion how i delete the characters in my char[] and fill it everytime the user put some input in it

Comment: *I know that I need somehow to refresh my char[]* - no you don't. There is no need for a character array. A text area uses a Document. When you type a character a DocumentEvent is generated. You can then update the Document of the second text area. There is no need to keep the data in an array.

Comment: I'm done.  You keep adding requirements to the question.  When you learn to properly describe a problem, then you might get some help.  Otherwise, figure it out yourself.

Comment: @camickr pls check my edit hope you get now why i use an char array to store data.

Comment: *is also descriped in the link in the comments.* - all the information relevant to the question should be posted with the question, not in the comments or in another question. You still haven't posted [mre]. You post random bits of code be we don't know the logical connection between the code.

Comment: @camickr the  3 code is the posted minimal reproducible example which work and was used by Gilber Le Blanc! And the pic makes it visible what my problem is. i left everything in there and described it as best as i can do so everyone can follow the process.

Comment: @KarebCN  The code posted by Gilbert was in a single source file so we can easily copy/paste/compile and test. Your code is presented in pieces and we don't know how it should be merged together. A [mre] should be posted as a single block of code that we can easily copy/paste/test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stringManipulator(textArea.getText());
```

From what I can see from the random pieces of code it appears that you process the entire text in the text area every time a single character is added.

Therefore your code should be something like:

```
textArea1.setText("");
stringManipulator(textArea.getText());
```

This will clear the old text from the output text area before you start appending new text (which will get rid of the yellow highlighted text).

Also, note:

1. you need to handle the case when text is deleted.
2. you should NOT be using static variables or methods. The text areas should be instance variables in your class. The example from Gilbert shows how to do this.

Comment: Thanks! setText("")  did the trick. To handle the case when something is deleted i will do the same like when something is added(which i already tested and does work). And yes i will change the static variables from my textArea and use instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the third time's a charm.

Here's what the OP wants to do.

> I want to manipulate user input like a decoder. you can imagine it with words and changing the font on the right side I get the input from the user and the left side is the output that I define in my stringManipulator method. the user will see directly what is happening that's why two text areas and to be able to manipulate the input.

Okay, that's something I can work with.

Here's a double JTextArea GUI I created.

[image: Decoder GUI]

The "trick" is to create a pair of Strings, like this.

```
    String inputLetters = "Ggilbert";
    String outputLetters = "KKarebCN";
```

Since you're mixing upper-case and lower-case letters, this encoder will not decode.  In other words, which letter do I decode for K?  Is it g or G?

You put all the input letters in the first `String` and the corresponding coded letters in the second `String`.  Because of my comment in the previous paragraph, I recommend you create 52 unique transformations, 26 for the upper-case alphabet and 26 for the lower-case alphabet.  That way, you can encode going from `inputLetters` to `outputLetters`, and decode going from `outputLetters` to `inputLetters`.

You still have to code for all three methods of the `DocumentListener`.

Here's the complete runnable code.  Class names start with an upper-case letter.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class JTextAreaExampleGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JTextAreaExampleGUI());
    }

    private JTextArea textArea1;
    private JTextArea textArea2;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTextArea Example GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        textArea1 = new JTextArea(10, 40);
        Document document = textArea1.getDocument();
        document.addDocumentListener(new MyListener());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea1);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.BEFORE_LINE_BEGINS);
        
        textArea2 = new JTextArea(10, 40);
        textArea2.setEditable(false);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea2);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.AFTER_LINE_ENDS);


        return panel;
    }

    private class MyListener implements DocumentListener {
        
        String inputLetters = "Ggilbert";
        String outputLetters = "KKarebCN";

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
            String text = textArea1.getText();
            textArea2.setText(replaceLetters(text));
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
            String text = textArea1.getText();
            textArea2.setText(replaceLetters(text));
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent event) {
            String text = textArea1.getText();
            textArea2.setText(replaceLetters(text));
        }
        
        private String replaceLetters(String input) {
            String output = "";
            
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
                char c = input.charAt(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < inputLetters.length(); j++) {
                    char t = inputLetters.charAt(j);
                    if (c == t) {
                        c = outputLetters.charAt(j);
                        break;
                    } 
                }
                
                output += Character.toString(c);
            }
            
            return output;
        }
        
        

    }

}
```

Comment: to understand my char[]pls check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65431509/check-neighbours-in-a-string-with-java i do manipulate some of the chars thats why i need to store them first in an array

Comment: @KarebCN: In English, or whatever language you're most familiar with, **What are you trying to accomplish?**  What is your problem statement?  [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: i want that my charr array refresh with every input. that everytime user input the getText will be activ and the old getText that is still in my array will be deleted

Comment: @KarebCN: Sorry, but that's not a description of the overall goals of your project.  We're done unless you answer my questions.

Comment: i want to manipulate user input like a decoder. you can imagine it with word and changing the font on the right side i get the input from the user and the left side is the output that i define in my stringManipulator method. the user will see directly what is happening thats why two textarea and to be able to manipulate the inputthe way i want i need an array. The array is the problem

Comment: @KarebCN: Okay, we're making progress.  Give me a couple of examples of what you want to change.  The code in your question doesn't change anything (j -> j is not a change).

Comment: Le Blanc check the picture and if you want to try it yourself just replace my last edit in the stringManipulator method

Comment: @KarebCN: See my yet again updated answer.

Comment: i appriciate your answer but thats not what i am looking for i updated my question again i hope that makes clear with the pic what i want to achieve